# Minimizing MYSQL connection from webhook callback

Tags: php, mysql, api, callback, query-optimization

I am working on a project that requires my server xyz.com to receive POST/GET responses to xyz.com/callback.php  from abc.com(SMS gateway providers).

Below is how i currently handle the responses on callback.php

**1. Receive the POST data from abc.com (This post contains a unique ID)**

**2. Connect to mysql database and UPDATE users WHERE messageId=Same_ID_from_POST_data**

This works and data is being updated. However it is causing CPU overload due to the thousands of MYSQL connections. This is because whenever there is a delivery receipt from the api server for each individual message, callback.php connects to mysql and updates the database.

Is there a best practice to minimize the amount of times i connect to MYSQL?
I was thinking of doing the following, i however doubt if it makes any sense.

**1. Receive post data from api server as before.**

**2. Instead of updating mysql, i simply write to a .txt file with the following code**

$query.="Update users set status='$post_data_for_status' where unique='$post_unique';

Then after about 10mins i use cron to run a php file that uses mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) to update the table thereby making it a single connection. After the update i simply unlink the .txt file

Even if the above method will work, i don't know how to do it. I am sure there is a better alternative.

Any ideas please and sorry for long epistle.

Comment: I guess what i basically want is the best method to handle delivery receipts from external api callback without connecting to MYSQL per individual receipt.

Comment: The php APIs for using MySQL (`mysqli` and `PDO`) both have a connection pooling feature. So your php webhook responder should not be establishing a new database connection, but rather reusing an existing one, each time a webhook hits it. So, your problem seems to be the performance of your `UPDATE` query. Can you [edit] your question to show us the definition of the users table, including indexes? We also need to see the exact query you are using to `UPDATE`.

Comment: Be aware that the file queue is a point of vulnerability -- if a crash occurs, some number of receipts may get lost.

Comment: How many of these posts are per second??

Comment: @RickJames during broadcasts, we get tens of posts per second. At that point the server starts giving http500 internal error due to MYSQL eating up all of the cpu.

Comment: Let's see the slow queries.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for sounds like avoiding connection churning, which is one of the benefits we get from using a "connection pool", commonly used in Java/J2EE web applications.

PHP doesn't provide connection pooling (AFAIK). But PDO and mysqli do provide for "persistent" connections, which give some of the same benefit as connection pool (avoiding connection churning.)

For mysqli, prepend "`p:`" to the hostname in the `mysqli_connect`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

For PDO, include `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` in the connection.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Be aware that with persisted connections, the MySQL connection maintains it's state (session variables, temporary tables, user defined variables, et al.) For example, if a client issues a statement such as `SET time_zone = '+00:00';` or `SET @foo = 'bar';`, a subsequent client reusing that MySQL connection is going to inherit the `time_zone` setting or the user defined variable `@foo` value; whatever changes to the MySQL session state the previous clients made.